# Unity: stop/play only background music

Tags: unity, sound, music, sound-effects

I have a music sound clip simply drag-n-dropped to my hierarchy. I also have other sound effects in my game. I want to pause/play background music on button press but only music, not all sound effects. How can I reach this music `GameObject` in C# code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access any object in your hierarchy by [searching for it](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html):

```
GameObject soundObject = GameObject.Find("BackgroundSoundObjectName");
```

Then you're likely going to want to access the [AudioSource component](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html):

```
AudioSource audioSource = soundObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
```

Then you can use the [`Pause()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Pause.html) and [`Play()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html) methods of the audio source to control the music.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple audio sources, `FindObjectsOfType` might be useful (The `UnityEngine.Object` part is unnecessary if called from a `MonoBehaviour`-inherited script):

```
AudioSource[] allAudioSources =
    UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType<AudioSource>();
```